# LockDisplay: Unable to load X11 when using JNA to lock display

Tags: java, linux, x11, jna

I am trying to lock the display (disallowing the user to use the keyboard and mouse) in Java, using X11 through JNA.

However, when I try running the application on Windows, I get this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'X11': com.sun.jna.Native.open(Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:166)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:239)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:140)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:393)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:378)
    at com.sun.jna.platform.unix.X11.<clinit>(X11.java:347)
    at octostar.LinuxHelper.blockInput(LinuxHelper.java:77)
    at .... ....
```

My code is this (the input parameter is a boolean 'block'):

```
        boolean returnVal = true;
        X11.Display dpy = null;
        final X11 x11 = X11.INSTANCE;
        final Xss xss = Xss.INSTANCE;

        try {
            dpy = x11.XOpenDisplay(null);
            if (block)
                xss.XLockDisplay(dpy);
            else
                xss.XUnlockDisplay(dpy);

        } catch (Exception ex){
            returnVal = false;
        } finally {
            if (dpy != null)
                    x11.XCloseDisplay(dpy);
            dpy = null;
        }

        return returnVal;
```

The error occurs at X11.INSTANCE (which is the line octostar.LinuxHelper.blockInput(LinuxHelper.java:77) as in the error message above)

In another part of my code, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.platform.unix.X11
    at octostar.LinuxHelper.getIdleTimeMillis(LinuxHelper.java:50)
```

I tried typing X11 in terminal, and they told me to do an installation, which I did after that, but every subsequent time I type X11 it says it's not installed. When I type the installation command though, I am told that I have the latest version already.

This is all very confusing to me. If anyone could help shed some light on this I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Are you talking about the `com.sun.jna.examples.unix.X11.Display` class ? I tend to think so.

Comment: X11 is not an executable program, so typing "X11" isn't going to run anything.  It's a collection of libraries (and programs); you need the "client" libraries in order to call X11 library functions through JNA.

Comment: @Riduidel which part are you talking about? the error occurs at the part where I try to get an instance of X11, but yes, I am eventually trying to get the display through x11.XOpenDisplay(null)

Comment: @technomage Ahh, yes... Actually I was just trying my luck with typing X11 in the console (because I'm not too familiar with linux). I was wondering whether it was possible that it didn't exist in my computer and I needed to install it (since the error kept saying that it couldn't load) or if it could give me some kind of helpful message. Since a message did come up, I followed it and just got more confused. As you can tell, I'm a bit of a noob at this.

Comment: Microsoft Windows doesn't normally include X11 - have you installed some version of X11 on the system, or do you not mean Microsoft's OS when you say "when I try running the application on Windows" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JNA needs to be able to find libX11.so* when it looks up the functions you're calling.  On linux, you may need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the path to the X11 libraries.

(from the comments): LD_LIBRARY_PATH must be used in order to find dependent libraries, but setting the system property jna.library.path will allow you to indicate where explicitly loaded libraries may be found (i.e. those loaded with Native.loadLibrary()).

Comment: I did a quick search online, but it seems like editing the LD_LIBRARY_PATH seems to be discouraged? Is there a way to programatically link to the library?

Comment: I tried opening the file /etc/ld.so.conf and then editing it. Originally, the file had this: include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
I edited it so that it was /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf on one line and then /etc/lib on the next, and then running ldconfig -v. The same errors still occur. I've tried deleting everything and just placing /usr/lib in the file, appending the /usr/lib behind the original text with a comma in between or with a space in between and they all don't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try setting jna.library.path to include the path to libX11.so, e.g.

java -Djna.library.path=/some/path:/some/other/path ...

You *don't* want to edit system files for this purpose.

Comment: Check to see if there's a version of JNA already installed on your system.

Comment: I managed to remove the error and checked that I did manage to get the display, although locking the screen still doesn't work - I don't know why, by linking to the library using this:
System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "/usr/lib");
Thanks!

Comment: If you're running this on Windows, the X server is unlikely to be able to lock the display, unless that is explicitly noted as a feature of your X server.  I doubt the cygwin version will do so, althought the Xceed version might.